# Are rows sorted in Cassandra Memtable

Tags: cassandra

Are rows sorted in Memtable? According to this post:
http://distributeddatastore.blogspot.com/2013/08/cassandra-sstable-storage-format.html

An index will be created when Memtable is flushed into storage (Index.db file). Having a separate index, do rows still need to be sorted in memtable ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the writes are stored in the Memtable in sorted order. Check [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataWritten.html).